# Ball bouncing/moving inside an invisible box ios/xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'd like to make it when the user shakes the device the ball rattles around inside the object on screen. I'm assuming I need to set up an invisible box for it to collide with. It doesn't matter if it moved randomly or follows a predefined path, whichever is easiest.

I think I understand the "Activate on shake" part of the code, just the ball/object movement I'm not sure of

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
//You need an @property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *animator; in your .h
self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.viewToBounceAroundIn];

UICollisionBehavior *collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.viewThatBouncesAround]];
collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
[self.animator addBehavior:collision];

UIPushBehavior *push = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.viewThatBouncesAround] mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
push.magnitude = 1; //Play with this, it's how much force is applied to your object
push.angle = 0; //play with this too
[self.animator addBehavior:push];
```

I typed this away from a compiler - let me know if it works. The idea is that you use [UIKitDynamics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDynamicAnimator) as a physics engine, use a [UICollisionBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollisionBehavior_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollisionBehavior) to let the item bounce around inside the box, and a [UIPushBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPushBehavior_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPushBehavior) to apply the initial force.

If the item slows down too quickly for you, or loses too much energy when it bounces off walls, you can adjust its properties:

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior *behavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.itemThatBouncesAround]];
behavior.friction = 0; //no friction. play with this.
behavior.elasticity = 1;; //completely elastic, play with this.
[self.animator addBehavior:behavior];
```